# Change width of a lookup column

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I've created a lookup with two columns, first one containing and integer which works just fine but the second one has a long name and this is where the problem arises. Users should horizontally scroll in order to check the entire string and even in that case, the column's width is not big enough to display the whole data.

I've found this :

[Adjusting column width on form control lookup](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/161901)

But i don't understand exactly where and what to add.

I am not sure but maybe I have to add the fact that this lookup is used on a menu item which points to an SSRS report, in the parameters section.

**Update 1:**

I got it working with a lookup form called like this :

```
Args args;
FormRun formRun;
;

args = new Args();

args.name(formstr(LookupOMOperatingUnit));
args.caller(_control);
formRun = classfactory.formRunClass(args);
formRun.init();
_control.performFormLookup(formRun);
```

and in the init method of this form i added:

```
public void init()
{
    super();
    element.selectMode(OMOperatingUnit_OMOperatingUnitNumber);
}
```

meaning the field i really need.

[image]

I am not sure i understand the mechanism completely but it seems it knows how to return this exact field to the DialogField from where it really started.

In order to make it look like a lookup, i have kept the style of the Design as Auto but changed the **WindowType** to **Popup**, **HideToolBar** to **Yes** and **Frame** to **Border**.

Comment: Just change the `Style` property to *Lookup*

Comment: Look at form `FiscalCalendarYearLookup` `init` and `run` methods to add correct behavior.

Comment: You could create an alternate extended data type for your target field, then you not need any calling code.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen If i change the Style to Lookup, it will behave just like before, when i wasn't able to see the entire string or resize it.. i will have a look FiscalCalendar....

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best route is do a custom lookup and change the extended data type of the key field to reflect that. In this way the change is reflected in all places. See form `FiscalCalendarYearLookup` and EDT `FiscalYearName` as an example of that.

If you only need to change a single place, the easy option is to override `performFormLookup` on the calling form. You should also override the `DisplayLength` property of the extended data type of the long field.

```
public void performFormLookup(FormRun _form, FormStringControl _formControl)
{
    FormGridControl grid = _form.control(_form.controlId('grid'));
    grid.autoSizeColumns(false);
    super(_form,_formControl);
}
```

This will not help you unless you have a form, which may not be the case in this report scenario.

Starting in AX 2009 the kernel by default auto-updates the control sizes based on actual record content. This was a cause of much frustration as the sizes was small when there was no records and these sizes were saved! Also the performance of the auto-update was initially bad in some situations. As an afterthought the grid control `autoSizeColumns` method was provided but it was unfortunately never exposed as a property.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. is there any chance i can create a form, open it from the lookup method, pick a line and then return the desired field ? Maybe something like this : https://ax4dev.wordpress.com/tag/performformlookup/

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? Stick to the standard way of doing things, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can extends the sysTableLookup class and override the buildFromGridDesign method to set the grid control width.

```
protected void buildFormGridDesign(FormBuildGridControl _formBuildGridControl)
{
    if (gridWidth > 0)
    {
        _formBuildGridControl.allowEdit(true);
        _formBuildGridControl.showRowLabels(false);
        _formBuildGridControl.widthMode(2);
        _formBuildGridControl.width(gridWidth);
    }
    else
    {
        super(_formBuildGridControl);
    }

}
```